# Open vscode from terminal in diff mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open vscode from terminal in diff mode?

Something like `code file1 file2 --diff`.

If not this should be a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows platforms the correct syntax is:

```
code -d file01 file02
```

You may find this and other useful command line arguments by typing

```
code --help
```

I'm currently running VSCode v1.3.0. Hope this helped.

Comment: Works on macOS and Linux as well.